# Maintaining Child / Parent relationship between controls

Tags: c#, user-interface, user-controls, polymorphism, parent-child

I'm coding a WP7 GUI and have designed a Control class, and a ParentControl class that derives from Control and has a list of child controls. However, when adding a child to a ParentControl instance, I'm unable to access the child's parent reference because I set it to be 'protected' from users of the controls.

**The exact error is**

---

*"Cannot access protected member 'Control.Parent' via a qualifier of type 'Control';

the qualifier must be of type 'ParentControl' (or derived from it)"*

---

```
    public abstract class Control //such as a button or radio button
    {
        public ParentControl Parent { get; protected set; }
    }


    public abstract class ParentControl : Control //such as a panel or menu
    {
        protected List<Control> children = new List<Control>();;

        public void AddChild(Control child, int index)
        {
            NeedSizeUpdate = true;

            if (child.Parent != null)
                child.Parent.RemoveChild(child);
            child.Parent = this; //How do I access the parent?
            children.Insert(index, child);

            OnChildAdded(index, child);
        }
    }
```

---

**How might I fix this?**

Comment: I strongly suggest never ever using `Control` as a custom class name

Comment: Similar SO Post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567705/why-cant-i-access-c-sharp-protected-members-except-like-this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is because other things may derive from `Control`, and `ParentControl` can only access base members of controls it derives from. For instance, if `Control2` derived from `Control`, then `ParentControl` would not derive from `Control2` and so could not access it's base members.

So, you either make `Parent` a public property, or if you want to keep it hidden away from general users of the control, you could make access via an interface, and implement it explicitly:

```
interface IChildControl
{
    ParentControl Parent { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Control : IChildControl //such as a button or radio button
{
    ParentControl IChildControl.Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The explicit implementation (`IChildControl.Parent`) means that consumers with just a `Control` instance will not see the `Parent` property. It must be explicitly cast to `IChildControl` to access it.