# To access Protected Field of Parent class in child class

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to access protected member variables in different ways in the child class. I found I can not do so by using object reference of child class to parent class object. Here I am referring to "int Number6" in the following program.

However I can access "int Number7" which is public. I want to know the reason behind this.

```
public class Customer
{
    #region Fields



    protected int Number2; 
    protected int Number3;
    protected int Number4;
    protected int Number5;
    protected int Number6;

    public    int Number7;

    #endregion


}

public class CorporateCustomer : Customer
{
    public void PrintID()
    {
        CorporateCustomer CC = new CorporateCustomer();
        CC.Number2 = 101;

        base.Number3 = 103;

        this.Number4 = 104;            

        Customer C2 = new CorporateCustomer();
        C2.Number6 = 106; //->  Not Possible to access protected Number6 by this way                        

        C2.Number7  = 105; //-> However, can access public field                 

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't I access C# protected members except like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567705/why-cant-i-access-c-sharp-protected-members-except-like-this)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question - [the msdn states that this won't work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx):

> A protected member of a base class is accessible in a derived class
>   only if the access occurs through the derived class type.

Since you are using the basetype instead of the derived type, consequently this does not work.

But why? I could imagine that this relates to the issue that a Customer could also be derived by another class than CorporateCustomer. In this case the instance that you assigned to Customer would not necessarily be a CorporateCustomer and so the protected attribute correctly forbids to access the Number6 property because it would break the accessibility restriction.

```
    public class PrivateCustomer : Customer
    {
    }

    public class CorporateCustomer : Customer
    {
        public void PrintID()
        {

            Customer C = new PrivateCustomer();
            C.Number6 = 106; //->  Not Possible to access protected Number6 by this way which is alright, as this is not a Corporate Customer                       

            C.Number7 = 105; //-> However, can access public field                 

        }
    }
```

The C# Language Specification states exactly this example as a reason this doesn't work:

> 3.5.3 Protected access for instance members When a protected instance member is accessed outside the program text of the class in which it
>   is declared, and when a protected internal instance member is accessed
>   outside the program text of the program in which it is declared, the
>   access must take place within a class declaration that derives from
>   the class in which it is declared. **Furthermore, the access is required
>   to take place through an instance of that derived class type or a
>   class type constructed from it. This restriction prevents one derived
>   class from accessing protected members of other derived classes, even
>   when the members are inherited from the same base class.**