# Cannot access protected members from a derived class

Tags: c#, scope, protected, derived-class

So I just found what appears to be strange behavior (at least to me) of the C# compiler.

Take a look at the following demo code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChildClass c = new ChildClass();
        c.parentInstance = new ChildClass();
        c.ChildPublicMethod();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class ParentClass
{
    public ParentClass parentInstance = null;

    protected void ProtectedMethod(string arg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arg=\"{0}\"", arg);
    }

    public void ParentPublicMethod()
    {
        ProtectedMethod("Parent's public method.");
    }
}

public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public void ChildPublicMethod()
    {
        ParentPublicMethod();
        ProtectedMethod("Child's protected method");

        ((ChildClass)parentInstance).ProtectedMethod(
                "A different child's protected method.");
        //parentInstance.ProtectedMethod(
        //      "A different child's protected method."); //Compile time error.
    }

}
```

In the `ChildClass.ChildPublicMethod()` function, I expected that I could access the protected member by the commented out code.  After all, shouldn't the compiler have all of the necessary information to be able to tell that it is a safe access?  It knows `parentInstance` is of type `ParentClass`, it knows `parentInstance` is accessed from a descendant of `ParentClass`, so why is the compiler complaining anyways?

Apparently, performing a cast seems to fix everything.  **So what exactly is the difference between these two calls:?**

```
((ChildClass)parentInstance).ProtectedMethod(
        "A different child's protected method.");
//parentInstance.ProtectedMethod(
//      "A different child's protected method."); //Compile time
```

**Afterthought:**
The only possible explanation that I can come up with is that the C# compiler needs to be 100% certain that the `parentInstance` is indeed descendant of `ChildClass`.  If there was a class, say `ChildClass2 : ParentClass`, it would be incorrect to be able to access it's protected members from within `ChildClass` because `ChildClass` does not derive from `ChildClass2`.  Casting to `ChildClass` tells the compiler that you expect the `parentInstance` to be a `ChildClass` instance, and not some other descendant of `ParentClass`.

However, there is another issue I see.
Suppose I set the variable such that:

```
c.ParentInstance = new ParentClass();
```

In this case, `ChildClass` cannot access the protected method (not even with a cast, since it cannot be casted to anything else containing the protected method).  Why is this so?
**If the instance is clearly a `ParentClass` and nothing more, why shouldn't the `ChildClass` be able to access its protected method?  Or is it possible?**

---

#### EDIT:

Apparently, there seems to be a misunderstanding of what I'm asking.  Yes I realize that cannot access the `ParentClass` instance.  However, I am concerned what is the reasoning behind this so that I can understand *why*.

Is my above *afterthought* correct?  Am I understanding this properly?

Thanks.

Comment: what about  `base.ProtectedMethod(
                  "A different child's protected method."); //Compile time error.` ?

Comment: This question [Why can't I access C# protected members except like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567705/why-cant-i-access-c-sharp-protected-members-except-like-this) covers your issue and may shed some insight into the issue you're having.

Comment: I've edited to post to try and clarify what I am asking.  Perhaps the reasoning isn't publicly available, but I don't know.

Comment: As @Nuffin stated in his' answer, it's a security measure to prevent loop holes in your security from occurring. You can set the access modifiers as protected internal which should allow you to access the member within that assembly or other assemblies derived from the parent class but the security threat remains. Reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) should shed some light on what we're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly as you said. `parentInstance` *could* be an instance of `ChildClass2`, so exposing that object's protected members to your ChildClass would create a possible security threat.

Imagine the following scenario:
You have an extensible class `A`, which exposes some protected members to its derived classes (which might, for example, mutate protected state or call other, possibly virtual members) and a derived class `B`, which uses the base functionality to do some security critical stuff, while exposing only a safe API with all kinds of error and permission checking.

Now, would you really want anyone to be able to easily bypass those checks by simply deriving a class `C` from `A` which then could directly call the protected methods on an object of type `B`?

Answer (score 1):

*"A protected member of a base class is accessible in a **derived class only** if the access occurs through the derived class type."*

*"The type or member can only be accessed by code **in** the same class or struct, or **in** a derived class."*

In your line of code:

```
parentInstance.ProtectedMethod("A different child's protected method.");
```

'parentInstance' is not derived *from* 'ParentClass', it *is* a 'ParentClass'.

In your other line of code:

```
((ChildClass)parentInstance).ProtectedMethod("A different child's protected method.");
```

You have simply *told* the compiler that the ParentClass object should be treated as a ChildClass - and a ChildClass can access the protected members of the class it inherits from.

But, ultimately, the code will fail at run time, as a ParentClass cannot be cast to a ChildClass.

It's a little hard to explain, so if this doesn't make complete sense I'll try again. :)

**(I see you've changed your question, so this is probably not what you wanted. Ho hum.)**

Comment: Yes, this is the behavior I noticed, and it is consistent with the specs.  I think that Nuffin's answer gives the answer I'm looking for as it explains the reasoning behind it.  Apologies, I tend to ask many related things in the same post in hopes that I might get a thorough answer addressing the topic.

Comment: No problem. :) Maybe my answer will help someone else.